# Contar Datos En Un Array Antes De Enviar Por Post Con Js

Tags: javascript, array, contador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un array variable donde recopila datos de imagenes seleccionadas, cada imagen tiene como nombre un número, es decir que lo que seleccióno, el array lo recoge como el nombre de la imagen. ejemplo : Galeria de imagenes imagen 1 a 100, selecciono con un submit ( Cada Imagen tiene su submit por lo que solo con tocarla ya queda seleccionada ) img1, img 8, img 23, img 46, img 88, y enviar por post el dato de las imagenes seleccionadas. lo que necesito es controlar el numero de imagenes seleccionadas, y para eso necesito contarlas y si exede un numero determinado o es menor, muestre un alert. Ejemplo : Propongo 100 Jugadores De Fútbol Con Imagen y Debes Armar Tu Equipo Ideal, Seleccionas 11 , y envias tu equipo, cuado presionas "enviar", necesito una funcion que me cuente los datos ( Recuerden que el número es el nombre, o sea que podría ser 1 o Sanpetesburgo si estuviéramos eligiendo ciudades del mundo, lo que se debe contar es el dato sin importar su contenido) y que a tu equipo ni le falten ni sobren jugadores. Si pueden darme una idea se los voy a agredecer, ya que he visto muchas cosas y probado pero solo he conseguido que diferencie entre array vacio o con contenido pero no cuenta la cantidad de datos, ya que creo que solo toma un valor. les muestro con imagen lo que necesito.[![

```html
function hizoClick() {
  var seleccion = [numsArray];    
  if (seleccion == "") {
      alert("debes realizar tu selección  ."); 
  } 

  if  (seleccion < "x") {
     alert("Debes elegir x imagenes.")
  }

  else {
  alert("Enviado");
  }

}
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guc82.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guc82.png)

Comment: Los array tienen un atributo para eso: `numsArray.length` indica la longitud exacta del array... no tienes que hacer nada más para contarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria de esta forma

```
let seleccion = [];    
function hizoClick(seleccion) {   
  if (!seleccion.length) {
      return alert("debes realizar tu selección  ."); 
  } 

  // Si quiero que solo se puedan escoger un maximo de 10 imagenes
  if  (seleccion.length > 10) {
     //si hay mas de 10 entonces limpio todo el array para que las vuelvan a escoger
     seleccion.splice(0, seleccion.length);
     return alert("Debes elegir un maximo de 10 imagenes.")
  }

  alert("Enviado");

}
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu idea, te comento de esa manera salta directamente a else, ( Enviado) sin realizar comparación alguna ni si esta vacio el array  o con datos, y menos que menos hace el conteo.

Comment: Mala mia mira de nuevo ahi edite lo que te envie y checa si funciona

Answer (score 0):

al fin pude solucionarlo, el error principal era que estaba comparando el valor de un string vacio "" en ves de el valor numérico 0. eso provocaba una falla en numsArray.length ( Así se llama el array que recopila los datos de las imágenes seleccionadas ) y solo me daba que el array tenía datos o no sin realizar la cuenta de los mismos, Por eso la segunda comparación, ( <11) tampoco funcionaba.
Espero que le sea de utilidad a alguien.
Gracias a quienes leyeron aunque no pudieron o supieron compartir nada, y a dos amigos que aportaron sus ideas, aunque no funcionaron.